# What can I do about my institution taking a long time to correct a mistake in my transcript?

Tags: graduate-school, transcript-of-records, norway

In January of 2016, I completed a Master's in Library and Information Sciences in Norway.  My transcripts were verified and signed by three universities as it was a joint course in collaboration of three universities.

The transcripts appear to incorrectly list my grades in 4 courses as "*Recognized*" instead of providing the actual grades.  I didn't gave focus to that grades before because it was signed my the rectors of three universities so I thought may be that is some kind of grade.

[image]

Later on when I applied for a job in a company, they refused to grant me the job because of that error in my diplomas.

I then complained to my university about the error. After that, the universities send me temporary grade papers within few days by saying that they are going to send another copy of transcripts within a months as they have to have the transcripts signed by three universities' rectors.

The total process it took 1 year, which had wasted my time. So what shall I do to the universities regarding this issue?

Comment: Most likely nothing. What is your goal?

Comment: Are you asking what you should do *to* the universities, or *about the problem*?

Comment: Is this resolved? It appears to be. Did you still get a job in the meantime? Do you want to sue? Or are you just venting?

Comment: What is a "Recognized" grade? Is it a "pass" grade without further distinction? Is it like an Incomplete?

Comment: Yes, I am asking that what actions can I take toward the universities. As, I got an email from program coordinator as 'I am terribly sorry that the Diploma is incorrect. It should not have passed our quality control procedures. We will issue a new and correct diploma. '

Comment: Without researching these places, are you sure that this isn't a degree mill?  The story just sounds pretty suspicious.

Comment: @Nat It's quite a stretch to assume the universities are degree mills because there was an error on one transcript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Wait

You should do nothing. The universities made a mistake and claim to be fixing it. Unless you have a reason to believe they will not fix it, then you should do nothing but wait.

Mistakes happen and it is unfortunate.

If you have a reason to believe the universities are not honest and will not fix the issue, then you should edit that reason into the question.